# How to generate a Google Play upload key and keystore for a Flutter app in Android Studio?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, google-play

I'm trying to deploy my Flutter app to Android. According to the Flutter documentation, we have to [sign our apps](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#signing-the-app). The first step is to create an `upload keystore`. There are two ways to do this.

The first method uses Android Studio. The instructions say:

```
In the menu bar, click Build > Generate Signed Bundle/APK.
```

Here's a screenshot of `Build` in Bumblebee 2021.1.1:

[image]

Where is `Generate Signed Bundle/APK`?

I clicked `Build > Flutter > Build App Bundle`. This ran for a while and finished without error messages.

The second method uses the CLI. You enter this (on a Mac or Linux):

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

That prompted me for a `keystore password`. What is that and where do I get one?

I'm supposed to see an `upload-keystore.jks` file in my home directory. Does this mean in my project's home directory or my user's home directory? I don't see that file.

Next, I'm told to

```
Create a file named [project]/android/key.properties that contains a reference to your keystore:

storePassword=<password from previous step>
keyPassword=<password from previous step>
keyAlias=upload
storeFile=<location of the key store file, such as /Users/<user name>/upload-keystore.jks>
```

What password from what previous step? And where is the key store file located?

I apologize if this is all obvious to Android users. I've always used iPhones. I bought my first Android phone yesterday and this is completely baffling to me.

Comment: - `keytool -genkey -v -keystore` is for generating your new keystore for signing the apk.  
keystore password is your password for the generated keystore. When you entering it, the password won't be displayed.
`~/upload-keystore.jks` it means your current user home. On Mac, usually it is at `/Users/YourUsername/` directory.

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android

Answer (score 7):

Thank you @ישו אוהב אותך. The mistake is that when you run

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

it prompts you: `Enter keystore password:` It should say `Create new keystore password` or `Enter new keystore password`.

I made up a unique new password `swordfish` and entered it. I was prompted for my name and address and then told:

```
Warning:
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /Users/TDK/upload-keystore.jks -destkeystore /Users/TDK/upload-keystore.jks -deststoretype pkcs12".
```

So apparently there's a second item that needs to be updated in the documentation.

I ran the new command and now I see a file `upload-keystore.jks` in my user home directory (not in my project home directory).

I'll post a ticket with Flutter the make these two updates.

Comment: It is inexplicable to me that over a year after Thomas posted this, the first step in the official Flutter documentation for signing an app continues to refer to a menu option that does not exist.  Thanks Thomas for posting about this issue.

Comment: Seems that the menu item doesn't show due to not opening Android Studio at the `android` folder. 
Check out the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76819784/10044909.

Answer (score 2):

(If anyone facing this issue currently) You need to open your project's android folder in android studio, then only you will be able to see the Generate Signed Bundle/APK option.

Answer (score 1):

1- run this command:

```
keytool -genkeypair -v -keystore key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
```

2-Create a file named `key.properties` in the android directory of your project

3-Add the following lines and replace the placeholders with the values from the keystore you generated:

```
storePassword=toio123
keyPassword=toio123
keyAlias=key
storeFile=../app/key.jks
```

4-Open android/app/build.gradle and add the signing config:

```
android {
    ...
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

5- finally Run the following command:

```
flutter build appbundle --release
```